# WP Unit Test execution from Jenkins running as a Windows Service

Tags: unit-testing, windows-phone-8, windows-services

We integrate our Windows Phone apps with Jenkins to automate builds, unit test execution etc.

When we try to execute unit tests using the tool vstest.console.exe we got the following error,

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 11.0.60315.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> Starting test execution, please wait... Error: Could not start test
>   run for unit tests for Windows Phone app: Unit tests for Windows Store
>   apps cannot be run from a service or non interactive process. Please
>   run unit tests from an interactive process..

If we think about session 0 isolation this is not an unexpected error actually but i think there should be a way to automate unit test executions right? What is the work around?

Thanks

Comment: The explanation in the error message indicates there's some confusion: it says, "Unit tests for Windows Store apps cannot be run..."  So maybe the command line is missing some argument to specify Windows Phone app? Can you post a sample command line that you are using?

Comment: I think its just an error message/typo mistake. I successfully automated unit tests by changing the communication type of jenkins. Instead of running slave node as a windows service, we now use the JLNP.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We changed the slave nodes' **Launch Method**. Instead of using "**Let Jenkins control this slave as a windows service**" option we use **JLNP** option